# Remove dots and slash at the beginning on the link

Tags: jquery, html

i have an html like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
      <tr>
           <td><a href="../directory/place/main/?qs=sample">Some Text</a></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

how do i remove the ../ on the href attribute using JQUERY?

Comment: please show us what have you tried until now.

Comment: actually im about to replace atleast this relative path (../) to space or something like a link i used this code but to no avail

`$('a').each(
    function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('href');
     if (src.indexOf('.') === 0){
            this.src = src.replace(/\.\.\//g,'http://sample.com/');
  }
    });`

Comment: id's should be unique. by your `each` i understand you have more then one link with the id 'a'.

Comment: what's your idea upon doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#mytable a').each(function(){
                var str = this.href;
                this.href = str.substring(3);

            });
        })
```

if you don't have ../ in every href you can try below code

```
  var str = this.href;
  this.href = str.replace('../', '');
```

Comment: it ommits 3 strings from the start.. the results has gone like this:
p://localhost/directory/place/main/?qs=sample

Comment: this one works i just add another command line with replacing http://localhost to the links i want to replaced

`var str = this.href;
this.href = str.replace('../', '');
this.href = str.replace('http://localhost', 'http://www.sample.com/');`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. tho others answers might have work as well.. thanks guys for contributing..

Answer (score 0):

Removing "../" is what you just want to do?

```
var a = $('a'); // Selector for anchor
var href = a.attr('href');
href = href.replace('../', '');
a.attr('href', href);
```

Answer (score 0):

id's should be unique (only one per page).
your code works fine as soon as you define it as a class instead.
http://jsfiddle.net/QsgPT/3/

```
<a href="../directory/place/main/?qs=sample" class="a">Test</a>

$(function(){
$('.a').each( function(){ 
        var src = $(this).attr('href'); 
        if (src.indexOf('..') === 0){ 
            this.src = src.replace(/\.\.\//g,'http://sample.com/');
        } 
    });

alert($('.a')[0].src);
});
```

Comment: i have a table id.. and the anchor link doesn't have class.  ill edit the html sample above..